# Unable to drag and drop in selenium for only this website

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop, selenium-chromedriver

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); //Launch the chrome browser
driver.get("https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/drag-and-drop-demo.html");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"todrag\"]/span[2]"));
WebElement from = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"todrag\"]/span[2]"));
WebElement to = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='mydropzone']"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.dragAndDrop(from, to).perform();
```

Comment: Should add debug to check whether your selector successfully got the expected element. Sometimes if element is on the page but out of the viewport selenium will fail to select them.

Answer (score 0):

I put it in Junit test. Works fine for me.

But I noticed you're not setting property to use a local chromedriver.

Have you got a [chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) downloaded?

```
    private WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                //"C:/path/to/your/chromedriver.exe"
                "/path/to/your/chromedriver"); // Might be this.
        driver= new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void testDragNDrop() {
        driver.get("https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/drag-and-drop-demo.html");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"todrag\"]/span[2]"));
        WebElement from = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"todrag\"]/span[2]"));
        WebElement to = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='mydropzone']"));
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        builder.dragAndDrop(from, to).perform();
    }
```